# Можно-ли при сборке на buildozer apk интегрировать в него онлайн часть

Tags: python-3.x

Я делаю приложение для андроид на kivy, собирая его на buildozer. У меня возник вопрос: можно ли туда интегрировать онлайн часть (работу с онлайн диском, обмен данными с таким-же приложением на другом смартфоне). Я пробовал yadisk и webdavclient3, но при открытии его на телефоне оно выдаёт ошибку(charset-normalizer (необходим для yadisk) требует 64 битное приложение, при сборке которого оно не устанавливается(устанавливаются только 32 битные)). Или может кто-то посоветует хостинг для сервера на socket(я искал но не получается подключиться к их адресам, слишком большой тайм-аут(я не знаю какой айпи мне использовать)).

Comment: Укажите точный текст ошибки. По идее для нормализации символов не нужна обязательно 64-битная платформа.

Comment: dlopen failed: "/data/data/org.test.myapp/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/charset_normalizer/md.so" is 64-bit instead of 32-bit